# based on zip code show shipping rate drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

for my site based on zip code  shipping rate different if zip code in listed in my zip code then shipping rate zero other wise shipping rate add 15$ how it perform in drupal 7. i am not using drupal commerce.

Answer (score 0):

First thing ,your question is vague, its not properly explained.

Now , how are you trying to render that value , is it through Views or  Custom Theme via custom module. If you are using Custom module , then you have more control over how you want to render that value just applying simple logic pulling data from database. 
Alternatively if you are using the Views to render the value, I would suggest using 'hook_views_pre_render()' to alter the final value.